# Need an maths algorithm to encode number in big integer to integer

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, encode

I want to convert a number value of 100 digits into lessthan 10 digits and vice versa.
So I pass that encoded number to mobile user and on getting back can make 100 digits number again.
I want to use it in PHP, .NET or JS.

But before that I need an algorithm for that.

I have some idea to use simple divide-subtract and add-multiply options in my mind to implement. But need some more secure than that.

Comment: Secure? So do you mean in fact encrypt, rather than encode? And of course this isn't possible since there are lots of 100 digit numbers for each 10 digit number. Are there some tight restrictions on what the big integer can be? Can we use multiple 10 digit integers?

Comment: can you pass 10 digits or 10 bytes?

Comment: well ... there is no bijective mapping from the set of numbers up to (or equal) 100digits to the numbers less then 10 digits so this will get ... interesting.

Comment: 100 digits in, 10 digits out, back to (the same) 100 digits?  That's compression I'd say.  Good luck finding a compression algorithm that guarantees a compression factor of 10 on a 100 byte input block.

Comment: There are 10**100 possible 100-digit numbers, and only 10**9 numbers with less than 10 digits, so if you want to compress *any* 100-digit number, that's impossible in principle. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This doesn't sound anything like math to me

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the simple divide-subtract and add-multiply options? I don't think it's quite possible to compress 100 digits to 10 digits without some loss of data here ...

Comment: I think Shail may be thinking about converting base-10 number to (for example) base-256 number (fits in char). This would reduce length to ~42 digits. If base-2^32 would be used (4B integer), then this would reduce length to ~11 digits.

Comment: Can't we use square root, division and subtract or add formula???

How can I store long integer no in PHP it is converting with e formula

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is impossible. You are trying to pigeonhole 10^100 items into 10^10 boxes. Some box will get more than one item and so it's impossible to invert back to "the" original item.

You could encode the 100-digit base-10 numbers as a 56-digit base-62 number (use uppercase and lowercase Roman alphabet and digits 0-9). The math here is `100 * log(10) / log(62)`.

To encode using less than ten characters from some alphabet, you need an alphabet with ~2^34 symbols. The math here is `100 * log(10) / log(number of symbols)`. Good luck with that.

Comment: It's intuitively obvious that to encode 10 decimal digits into 1 (=100->10), you need 10,000,000,000 symbols in your alphabet.

Comment: I can't use any other than 0-9 digits(integers) only.
I am going to encrypt this no. to pass it to mobile application through server so I need it encrypted. As well on response I need it in decryption mode as well.

Comment: @Shail Patel: With the constraint that you can only use digits `0--9`, your problem is insoluble.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 10 000 000 000 different possible values in the 100 digit number you can not possibly map that to a 10 digit number and reliably map back to the original number.

Answer (score 0):

A 100 digit number, I assume this is a base ten number,  When talking about numbers on computers talk of 'digits' is almost meaningless.

If you actually mean a 100bit integer, then this wont easily fit into a single 64bit integer ( range +/- 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 ) then you have not phrased your question all that well. And no amount of compression or encoding will let you represent 100bits using no more than 10bits.

If you mean 100 figures in base ten, then you are dealing with bignums so should probably just treat them as bytes and use a bignum library.

100 base ten figures is still less than 512 bits.

Comment: @tom, it doesn't I got all flustered mid sentence :)

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Assuming that the 100-digit number is base 10, then if my math is not wrong you'll need 10 base 100 digits to represent the same number. So instead of using just characters from 0-9, you'll need to expand the characters to include other glyphs, including upper-case and lower-case letters, etc., to complete a 100 character alphabet.</strike> OK, my math is wrong, so disregard this, but consider the next paragraph.

Another thought is to use a hashing algorithm to derive a 10-byte hash from your 100-digit number and use that as key in a server-side database (hash-table). No encoding/decoding, just send the key to the mobile client, the mobile client uses the key to fetch the 100-digit number from the server.

Comment: 10 base 100 digits would only represent 20 base 10 digits. You need 10 base 10^10 digits.